# a random procedure

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to write some code, but there is a problem with my reply procedure. Ignore the procedures for the first two random-of-threes, but the problem is in the `else` when calling the `pick-random` procedure.  Here's the code:

```
(define earlier-responses '()) 

(define (doctor-driver-loop name earlier-responses)
  (newline)
  (write '**)
  (let ((user-response (read)))
    (cond 
      ((equal? user-response '(goodbye))
         (write-line (list 'goodbye name))
         (write-line '(see you next week)))
      (else 
         (list user-response earlier-responses)                    
         (write-line (reply user-response earlier-responses))
         (doctor-driver-loop name earlier-responses)))))

(define (reply user-response earlier-responses)
  (cond 
    ((= (random-of-three) 0)
      (append (qualifier)
              (change-person user-response)))
    ((= (random-of-three) 1)
      (hedge))
    (else
      (append (write-line '(earlier you said that))
              (pick-random earlier-responses)))))

(define (random-of-three)
  (random 3))

(define (pick-random lst)
  (nth (+ 1 (random (length lst))) lst))
```

It highlights

```
            (random (length lst))) lst))
```

It throws this error:

```
  random: contract violation
  expected: (or/c (integer-in 1 4294967087) pseudo-random-generator?)
  given: 0
```

I'm not sure what this error means or how to fix it...

Answer (score 2):

The error is simply stating that the lists' length is zero, and `random` expects a value between 1 and 4294967087. Pass a non-empty list when calling `pick-random`. This is what's happening:

```
(random 0)

=> random: contract violation expected: (or/c (integer-in 1 4294967087)
   pseudo-random-generator?) given: 0
```

Try defining `earlier-responses` with a non-empty list at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Oscar correctly answers the question you asked, but you have a worse error that you don't yet realize: You should calculate the random number once before entry to the cond expression rather than recalculating it in each cond clause. With your method you will not choose each of the three possibilities with equal probability. The first choice will be chosen about 1/3 of the time, the second choice will be chosen about 1/3 of the remaining 2/3 of the time, or 2/9, and the third choice will be chosen the remaining 4/9 of the time. You probably want all three choices to occur with equal probability.

Answer (score 1):

I think you know what time it is.

[dons [code-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) hat /]

Firstly, before we get to anything else, what version of Racket are you using?

I've got 5.2.1 here, so I may be a bit behind, but `nth` and `write-line` don't seem to be defined functions here. I think what you want is `list-ref` and `write`. Note that `list-ref` has a different argument order, and expects a zero-indexed reference into the list. In other words `(list-ref (list 1 2 3) 0) => 1`. You therefore probably want to define `pick-random` as

```
(define (pick-random lst)
  (list-ref lst (random (length lst))))
```

You also have a couple of undefined functions there which I assume you define elsewhere in your program (`hedge`, `qualifier` and `change-person`). I'll elide these in further comments.

---

As Óscar mentions, `random` takes an integer in the range of 1 to 4294967087. Which means that you want to account for that before passing a number to it. As a note, `(random n)` seems to return an integer between `0` and `(- n 1)` inclusive, so you don't need to add or subtract things yourself to get a random element out of a list.

```
(define (pick-random lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      lst
      (list-ref lst (random (length lst)))))
```

---

As user448810 mentions, you don't want to re-calculate `random-of-three` because that won't give you equal probabilities of each choice being made. Since you'll be pre-calculating it, you probably don't need the `random-of-three` function at all.

```
(define (reply user-response earlier-responses)
  (let ((rand (random 3)))
    (cond ((= rand 0)
           (append (qualifier)
                   (change-person user-response)))
          ((= rand 1)
           (hedge))
          (else
           (append (write '(earlier you said that))
                   (pick-random earlier-responses))))))
```

---

`write` doesn't actually return anything. It just prints something to the REPL, so the `else` clause of your `reply` function can't be what you mean unless `write-line` does something fundamentally different from `write`.

```
(else
 (append (write '(earlier you said that))
         (pick-random earlier-responses)))
```

You either want

```
(else
   (write '(earlier you said that))
   (write (pick-random earlier-responses)))
```

if you just want printed output, or

```
(else
   (let* ((res (list '(earlier you said that) (pick-random earlier-responses))))
     (write res)
     res))
```

if you meant to preserve the return value for future use somewhere.

---

Next, and this is probably the biggest bug I see as well as the easiest for Scheme newbies to make (so don't feel bad), you're not changing `earlier-responses` anywhere. The else clause in your `doctor-driver-loop`

```
(else (list user-response earlier-responses)                    
      (write (reply user-response earlier-responses))
      (doctor-driver-loop name earlier-responses))
```

creates a new list with your `user-response` as the head and `earlier-responses` as the tail, but you don't do anything with it. You also don't pass a different value into the next call to `doctor-driver-loop`. If you actually wanted to track input history, you would want that to look something like

```
(else (write (reply user-response earlier-responses))
      (doctor-driver-loop name (list user-response earlier-responses)))
```

---

**But** that wouldn't quite do what you seem to want it to either. The above would always pass a two-element list to the next iteration of your driver loop; the first element would be the most recent response and the second element would be `earlier-responses`.

```
> (list '(I need a perscription) '((how are you doing?) (hello))) 
((I need a perscription) ((how are you doing?) (hello)))

> (list '(are you even listening?) '((I need a perscription) ((how are you doing?) (hello))))
((are you even listening?) ((I need a perscription) ((how are you doing?) (hello))))
```

What you'd *really* want, if you want to be able to pick a random past response using `pick-random`, is a flat list of all responses. That means `cons`ing new responses rather than `list`ing them.

```
> (cons '(I need a perscription) '((how are you doing?) (hello)))
((I need a perscription) (how are you doing?) (hello)))

> (cons '(are you even listening?) '((I need a perscription) (how are you doing?) (hello)))
((are you even listening?) (I need a perscription) (how are you doing?) (hello))
```

So your `else` clause should be

```
(else (write (reply user-response earlier-responses))
      (doctor-driver-loop name (cons user-response earlier-responses)))
```

Answer (score 1):

(define random-4-digits
  (foldr (λ (n result)
           (cons n (map (λ (y) (if (>= y n) (add1 y) y))
                        result)))
         '()
         (map random '(10 9 8 7))))

Answer (score 0):

`(or/c (integer-in 1 4294967087) pseudo-random-generator?)`

is [an "or" contract](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/data-structure-contracts.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fcontract%2Fprivate%2Fmisc..rkt%29._or%2Fc%29%29) - meaning, to be accepted by this contract, the value (an argument to [`random` function](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html?q=random#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._random%29%29)) must be one of the following: either [an integer between](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/data-structure-contracts.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/contract/private/misc..rkt%29._integer-in%29%29) `1` and `4294967087`, inclusive, [**or**](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/data-structure-contracts.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fcontract%2Fprivate%2Fmisc..rkt%29._or%2Fc%29%29) an `object` such that [`(pseudo-random-generator? object)`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html?q=random#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._pseudo-random-generator~3f%29%29) returns `#t`.